# Increment count on defaultdict list

Tags: python

How to increment the count in `defaultdict` of list like

```
import collections
dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

`dict["i"][0]+=1` throws a type error.

I am expecting the dict to be like

```
{"i":[1,]}
```

Any efficient approach for this instead of using any loops statements?

Comment: Add the code snippet which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

s = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [0])

s['i'][0] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the item from the dict and then appending to it

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['i'].append(1)

>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'i': [1]})
```

Also don't use **dict** as a variable name, it is used to construct dicts.

```
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Counter** from collections

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
sample_list = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','e','b']
for l in sample_list:
    c[l] += 1
```

Now the variable **c** would give the following,

```
>>>Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})
```

You can get count of each element as follows:

```
c['a']
>>>2
```